# How to use micrometer, influx, and grafana in custom stream app?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Anyone know how to use micrometer, influx, and grafana in custom stream application ?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/html/_micrometer.html

i already follow instructions above but when i deploy the stream, my grafana dashboard doesn't show stream name, app name. the dashboard only shows the graph without the legend name

Answer (score 0):

we need more details,precise your question.